# onTouch with Multitouch and SoundPool Motion Events

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ontouchlistener, soundpool

So i'm making a xylophone app for android and i've run into a problem, i'm not sure how to correctly use onTouch. Right now I can press an image and play the sound, but I cannot play two sounds at once, nor can I slide my finger down the xylophone and play all the sounds, it will only play the first image pressed. I know this is because of onTouch and Multitouch but i'm not sure how to do this and I can't find any relevant sample code, any help is appreciated!

This is my main activity

```
public class Xylophone extends Activity {
private Player mSoundManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xylophone);
    mSoundManager = new Player();
    mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
    mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.note01);
    mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.note02);
    mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.note03);
    mSoundManager.addSound(4, R.raw.note04);
    mSoundManager.addSound(5, R.raw.note05);
    mSoundManager.addSound(6, R.raw.note06);
    mSoundManager.addSound(7, R.raw.note07);
    mSoundManager.addSound(8, R.raw.note08);

    ImageView img01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img01.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {    

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(1);
            return false;
        }           
    });

    ImageView img02 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    img02.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {    

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(2);
            return false;
        }           
    });
```

This is my SoundPool activity

```
public class Player {

private  SoundPool mSoundPool; 
private  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
private  AudioManager  mAudioManager;
private  Context mContext;


public Player()
{

}

public void initSounds(Context theContext) { 
     mContext = theContext;
     mSoundPool = new SoundPool(8, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); 
     mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
     mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);         
} 

public void addSound(int Index,int SoundID)
{
    mSoundPoolMap.put(Index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
}

public void playSound(int index) { 

     int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
     mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f); 
}

public void playLoopedSound(int index) { 

     int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
     mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, -1, 1f); 
}
```

}

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/button01" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/button02" />
```

Comment: I could really use a push in the right direction here, I tried reading up on motion events on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html but i'm just not grasping it, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully you figured it out until now. Still here's my shot at it:
First of all your second class, SoundPool, is **not** an activity.

What you have to try is not overriding each button's onTouch method.

---

Instead, in your main activity, make it implement OnTouchListener.

Then of course, you need to implement/override the OnTouchListener's methods. So now, if you register your main view and/or  every button(*see for yourself which works!*) to OnTouchListener, you will get all touches (multi touch as well).

Have a look at the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) class for more details

```
public class Xylophone extends Activity implements onTouchLister{
    public static final String TAG = "Xylophone";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*Either have your parent view register THIS (Xylophone) as its listener, or have each button register THIS(Xylophone) as its listener.*/
        yourParentView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        //or
        img02.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ID:" + Integer.toString(v.getId()));
        Log.i(TAG, "Pointer count: " + event.getPointerCount());        
        Log.i(TAG, "Action: " + event.getActionMasked());
        Log.i(TAG, "Action index: " + event.getActionIndex());
    }
```